# Replace a sequence of characters by another one

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a sequence of characters '-------' and i want to replace each '-' in it by each letter in 'jaillir' in the correct range.

How do i do that ?
Here is my code

```
import random

with open ("lexique.txt", "r", encoding= "utf8") as a:
     words = []
     letters = []
tirets= []
for line in a:
    ligne = line[:-1]
    words.append(ligne)
choix = random.choice(words)
tiret = ('-'* len(choix))
print(tiret)
print(choix)
accompli = False
while not accompli:
    lettre = input("Entrez une lettre du mot ")
    for t in range(len(tiret)):
        if lettre in choix:
            tiret.replace(tiret[t], lettre[t])
        print(tiret)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to fix your file reading code, even though it is not the question, as below:

```
with open('lexique.txt', r) as f:
    text = f.read() # get file contents
```

Next to replace the ---- by a word, I am assuming that the dashes in your text will only ever be the same length as the word, so:

```
word = 'word' # any string e.g. word
dashes = '-' * len(word)
```

So now you can use python's string.replace method like so:

```
text = text.replace(dashes, word) # every time it finds the sequence of dashes it will be replaced by your word
```

With a for loop (gradual replacement):

```
word = 'word' # any word
length = len(word)
temp = ''

for i, letter in enumerate(text):
    if letter == '-':
        if i + len(tempword) < len(text):
            characters = [True if l == '-' else False for l in text[i:i + len(tempword)]]
            if not(False in characters):
                new += tempword[0]
                if len(tempword) > 1:
                    tempword = tempword[1:]
                else:
                    tempword = word
            else:
                new += letter
    else:
        new += letter

print(new)
```

Comment: I want to replace each letter gradually by using "for"

Comment: I just added that to my answer, although it is not the most effective way

Comment: Thanks bro ! Appreciate it !

Comment: No problem, I would appreciate it if you could mark my answer as correct though, thanks